# Creating shapes without deleting mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, wireframe

[image]
Use wireframe on sphere can give me a good shape of holes without delete the mesh. I want to replace these holes with other shape like Heart or thunder. A shape of empty heart instead of a hole. How to do it ?

Comment: That would mean another approach to creating that sphere. It can be hand modeling one part and arraying all across the sphere or using dupliframes to spread objects along another (parent) object. Another way may be Tissue addon. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/tissue-addon-how-to-create-pattern-on-sphere

Comment: So, nothing easy will be done like wireframe. OK. the three methods you mentioned are good and i will try them. but what i was thinking on is can texture help me with this ? If i have black&white picture of a heart. can blender identify these heats and delete them from the sphere ? something easy.

Comment: Yes that's possible, use method described here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material. Basically it's just to create image of heart, setup 2 materials (or mix 2 shaders), make UV map so image of heart is placed on every face you choose and that should work. The basic setup may be like [here](http://imgur.com/SZTGa1P)